# Filemaker: Script which calls PHP code

Tags: filemaker

How can I write a script which calls my PHP code?
This script should contain records which are in Filemaker Database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filemaker with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368990/filemaker-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Insert from URL" script step to call PHP and make it do something.  I was able to use this in a server-side script to call a PHP script with some params in the URL.  This allowed me to have Filemaker talk to a PHP API of another service.  Not sure if that answers your question (or if it is even still a question), but thought that I'd share.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where I wanted a FileMaker action to trigger a script that would alert a website that something had changed. I was working in FileMaker Pro 11 so `Insert from URL` wasn't an option (though how I wish it had been)!

I created a FileMaker script called Sync and gave it one action: `Perform AppleScript` (obviously this works on Macs only; you can achieve something similar using `Send DDE Execute` in Windows).

In the Script Step Options, I set my `Perform Applescript` to be a `Calculated AppleScript`, and set it as follows:

```
"do shell script \"curl http://example.com/sync.php?id=" & Get( RecordID ) &
"\\\&layout=" & GetAsURLEncoded( Get( LayoutName ) ) & "\\\&table=" & 
GetAsURLEncoded( Get( LayoutTableName ) ) & "\""
```

Note all the quotes and escaping of quotes.

To cause this to execute when something changes, go to File » Manage » Layouts and select the layout where a user might be editing a record, then click `Edit`. In the resulting Layout Setup dialog, go to `Script Triggers` and for the event `OnRecordCommit`, select the Sync script you just created.

Now whenever a record is modified in that layout, the Sync script will run which executes the AppleScript which executes the shell command `curl`, sending a GET request something to the effect of:

```
curl http://example.com/sync.php?id=123&layout=Edit%20Records&table=Records
```

From there, create a `sync.php` to do something intelligent whenever it’s loaded, using `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['layout']` and `$_GET['table']` or similar passed-through variables.

One caveat with this approach is that FileMaker is frozen while the shell script executes, which in this case means until curl either receives a response or times out. While you can set the timeout to be very low (add arguments `--output /dev/null --silent --head --fail --connect-timeout 1`), it still causes a delay to the user of a second or so, which can be noticeable if a user is editing lots of records. If anyone has a solution for this, or a way to cause the script to run asynchronously in the background, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a PHP API available for FileMaker:

http://www.filemaker.com/downloads/pdf/article2_php.pdf

Comment: Can you tell me any Filemaker script if I'm retrieving records from 'Users' table and fields are 'username' and 'password' which are in Filemaker database. I wants to display all the records using php.

Comment: You won't want to call a FileMaker script for that purpose. A FileMaker script is similar to a stored procedure; you wouldn't call a stored procedure to simply select the contents of fields from a table. There are functions in the API to select fields from a table; just check the documentation.

Comment: Thanx Jesse
Now I'm using Filemaker API to retrieve the records but problem is,it is not retrieving records from Filemaker database.Can you tell me why this is happening..

Comment: No, I have no way of know why it's not working for you. You'll need to troubleshoot this based on the documentation and whatever error message you're getting.

Comment: I'm using Filemaker API in PHP to retrieve the records from Filemaker Pro 11 Advance Database. But its showing error.
Error: Communication Error: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 - This can be due to an invalid username or password, or if the FMPHP privilege is not enabled for that user.
Though I have set all Extend Privileges and gave it to user.

Answer (score -1):

Before you work on adding coding for your own file, try getting the sample API code to work with the FMServer_Sample database.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.